# Function for IndexedDB store methods execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, indexeddb

I want to create async function that receive function like

```
() => indexed_db_store.get_all()
or 
() => indexed_db_store.get(20)
```

and returns result of async operation: data from indexedDB.

So, here is a such function:

```
  async perform_indexed_db_action(action) {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      **const request = action();**
  
      request.onsuccess = () => {
        resolve(request.result);
        console.log('success');
      }
  
      request.onerror = (err) => {
        reject(err);
        console.log('error');
      }
    })
  }
```

but when I call it from code, for example:

```
const config = await this.perform_indexed_db_action(() => store.getAll());
```

**const request** becomes IDBRequest instance as it should be, but request.onsuccess or request.onerror doesn't work. Response don't get it.

What is the issue here? Help please.